# Drupal 7 change theme for module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-theming

I have created a new module based on the Extensible Wizard Example found in http://drupal.org/project/examples. This is a one of 5 form modules which will all run on the same drupal site.

I need all 5 modules to use different themes but cannot figure out how to set a theme on the module level.

I have tried the suggestions in [Drupal: How to theme a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500748/drupal-how-to-theme-a-module) and [Drupal theme functions workflow in module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328756/drupal-theme-functions-workflow-in-module) with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey, do you mean you want different themes on the different pages these modules create?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to do this programatically, you can use the themekey module api, as explained in this post: http://drupal.org/node/622450

Also there are several modules that would help with switching themes based on different circumstances from the frontend:

Themekey: http://drupal.org/project/themekey

Page Theme: http://drupal.org/project/page_theme

Content Theme: http://drupal.org/project/content_theme

There is also role theme switcher and some others

Comment: I ended up using Themekey. Thanks